# explicit typeof == "undefined" check vs just checking for its existence?

Tags: javascript

assuming x is an object...  Is there any benefit of doing:

```
 if (typeof x.foo != "undefined")
```

vs. doing

```
 if (x.foo)
```

?

This question came up as I was reading this blog post:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/

In his example, he does:

```
function EventTarget(){
  this._listeners = {};
}

EventTarget.prototype = {

  constructor: EventTarget,

  addListener: function(type, listener){
    if (typeof this._listeners[type] == "undefined"){
        this._listeners[type] = [];
    }

    this._listeners[type].push(listener);
```

In this case this._listeners[type] will never be anything except an array-- so is it not true that it would be cleaner in this case to just do

```
addListener: function(type, listener){
    if (!this._listeners[type]){
        this._listeners[type] = [];
    }

    this._listeners[type].push(listener);
```

?

Also, as a side question, I don't get why he's doing:

```
EventTarget.prototype = {

  constructor: EventTarget
```

Isn't the constructor by default already set to EventTarget ('this') when you call new EventTarget() ?

Comment: There is also a third alternative: `if (x.foo !== undefined)`. Notice the *double =* (equality without type coercion)

Comment: @Dan: Although that breaks if some fool changes `undefined`. Yes, that's possible.

Comment: @delnan True, but there are ways to guard even against that: `(function(undefined){ ...undefined is really undefined here...  }())`

Comment: Slaks?  my question is totally answerable?  Not sure what you mean..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Watch out for [truthy values](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

`if (x.foo)` will not run if x.foo is

- false
- null
- undefined
- ""
- 0
- NaN

Where as `if (typeof x.foo !== "undefined") {` only checks for whether the value is `undefined`

Alternative checks would be

`if (x.foo !== undefined) {` and `if (x.foo !== void 0) {`

Do be wary that `undefined` can be overwritten as a local variable

`undefined = true` is a valid statement and will break all your code. Of course you will never see this code in production so you don't really have to shield against it, it's just something to be wary of.

I personally tend to use

```
if (x.foo != null) {
    ...
}
```

a lot which checks for both `null` and `undefined`.

**[[Edit]]**

In your specific example it's either an `Array` or `undefined` so `!foo` is safe. personally I prefer to check specifically for `undefined` so that users know I only expect it to run when it's undefined rather then when it's `null` or `false` or `""`. This makes the code more explicit / self documenting.

As to

```
EventTarget.prototype = {

  constructor: EventTarget
```

If you overwrite `EventTarget.prototype` with a new object then the `EventTarget.prototype.constructor` property is lost and needs to be set again.

You do not need to set `.constructor` again if you just extend the prototype by calling `EventTarget.prototype.method = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The first explicitly checks that `x.foo` is `undefined`, whereas `if (x.foo)` is checking to see if `x.foo` is truthy.

http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript